# Unable to use TransactionScope with Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, transactionscope

I am attempting to use TransactionScope across two queries to different SQL Server instances (the transaction is promoted to MSDTC). I have it working synchronously without using Tasks but am unable to get the transaction to rollback when using Tasks asynchronously.

I have hidden both the connection strings to the servers and the update statements, but reast assured that they both connect and execute the SQL with no problems. I have intentionally set the SQL in the method `runTwo()` to fail and raise an exception.

I am using .Net 4.5.2 which includes the enumeration `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` (in the TransactionScope constructor) that I believe should handle a transaction across threads but am unable to get this to work.

```
static void Main()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                try
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => runOne()));
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => runTwo()));

                    Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                    //Complete the scope
                    scope.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Transaction.Current.Rollback();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void runOne()
        {
            //Get the base SQL connection
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER1....."))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandText = "Update .. Complete Successfully",
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    Connection = conn
                };

                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        private static void runTwo()
        {
            using (
                SqlConnection conn =
                    new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER2...")
                )
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandText = "Update .... Raises Exception",
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    Connection = conn
                };

                //Execute the command
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Is your problem. `Task.WhenAll` returns an *awaitable*, it doesn't *block* on the method call. Since you're using a console application which cannot be awaited, you'll have to defer to use `Task.WaitAll` instead which will explicitly block until both requests finish and will propagate any exception via `AggregateException`

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(new[] { Task.Run(() => runOne()), 
                         Task.Run(() => runTwo()) });
    scope.Complete();
}
```